# Is there a way to access images through .rar files?

Tags: python

I'm setting up a tkinter program which requires a lot of images, and I would like to have them organized into a .rar file or similar. Is there any way of doing this without extracting the files first like how you can view the files and open through the WinRAR program?

If so is there a specific imagetype I should use, or would any filetype be acceptable?

Comment: You may not believe this but winrar extract thoes images you are talking about. You need to extract your rar file, there is no other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, [`rarfile.RarFile.open`](https://rarfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#rarfile.RarFile.open) will do the job.